SPI Mode Selection
Im trying to determine SPI mode of CS5364.
Section 4.13.1 SPI Mode of the datasheet says:

CDOUT is the output data line to a controller. Data is clocked in on the rising edge of CCLK and is supplied on the falling edge of CCLK.

What exactly happens to CPOL AND CPHA in this case?

Is this settings right?

Have you looked at the reference manual how the CPOL and CPHA bits should be set, and then what settings to select in the GUI to get the settings you need?

Yes, I read the datasheet of the slave ADC audio integrated circuit 10 times, but I did not fully understand it.

Which GUI is being used for settings, and which microcontroller is in use? I agree the CS5364 datasheet doesn't use the terms CPOL and CPHA, so need to confirm how the microcontroller SPI peripheral defines those terms.

@Electronx Well you don't find it there, you need to read the MCU reference manual (not the data sheet) for what you need to know. And you already know what the audio chip needs to work.
